# How to jump to start and end of previous line from current line in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to jump to start and end of the previous line from the current line in IntelliJ? What is the keyboard shortcut to do that?
eg: I have two lines of code line1 and line2.Currently, the cursor is at line2. I want the keyboard shortcut to jump to end of line1.

Comment: There is no such keyboard shortcut.

Comment: ArrowUp then End?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such predefined keyboard shortcut. You can use [macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) to record, store and replay your personal navigation.

Furthermore, macros can be bind to a keyboard shortcut and that's what you want.